# Is increasing refcounts + move for strings threadsafe?

Tags: delphi, thread-safety

Provided that the Source array is located in a read-only collection, that can only be altered after a COW (copy-on-write) operation,
**is this method of cloning an array of strings thread safe?**

```
  for i:= Low(Source) to High(Source) do begin
    InterlockedIncStringRefCount(@Source[a]);
  end;
  Move(Source[0], Dest[0], Size * SizeOf(string));
```

Here's a sample application to see the clone in action.
The assisted move is twice as fast as `System.CopyArray`.
If I drop the interlock on the increment the speed doubles again 
(but then I need to lock the array whilst copying, which might cost more).

```
program Project10;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  System.Math
  //,FastMove
 ;
const
  Size = 100 * 1000;

function RDTSC: Int64;
asm
  RDTSC;
end;

procedure InterlockedIncStringRefCount(p: pointer);
asm
  mov eax,[eax]
  test eax,eax
  jz @done 
  mov ecx,[eax-8]
  inc ecx
  jz @done //Do not touch constant strings.
  lock inc dword ptr[eax-8];
@done: 
end;

var
  Source: array[0..Size] of string;
  Dest: array of string;
  i,a: Integer;
  StartTime: Int64;
  Duration, MinDuration: Int64;

begin
  for i:= 0 to Size do begin
    Source[i]:= IntToStr(i);
  end;
  SetLength(Dest, Size);
  //Assisted move
  MinDuration:= MaxInt;
  for i:= 0 to 100 do begin
    StartTime:= RDTSC;
    for a:= 0 to Size-1 do begin
      InterlockedIncStringRefCount(@Source[a]);
    end;
    {FastMove.}Move(Source[0], Dest[0], Size * SizeOf(string));
    Duration:= RDTSC - StartTime;
    MinDuration:= Min(Duration, MinDuration);
  end;
  Writeln('Assisted move took '+IntToStr(MinDuration div 1000)+' ticks');
  Readln;
end.
```

Comment: Why are you bothering with any interlocked operations if you are interested in perf?

Comment: I need it to be threadsafe. Two threads can clone an array at the same time. Because inc is not atomic. I need to use a lock or the refcounts will be off.  An alternative might be to lock the array, do x copies using Move and then add x to the refcount, so I only have to do one pass of the refcount increment.

Comment: Shared data is the enemy of performance

Comment: @mg30rg, have you noticed the `lock` prefix in the assembly....

Comment: @mg30rg, please do not be silly. InterlockedIncrement is a wrapper around the `LOCK INC dword ptr [EAX]` instruction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the proviso mentioned that `Source` is read-only, this code is thread-safe. It's doing essentially the same things as the *system* unit's implementation of string assignment, except that your code copies the references in bulk via `Move` instead of copying each string reference individually.

You mention the alternative of locking `Source` and then incrementing the reference counts without interlocked operations. That would be wrong. Locking `Source` doesn't do anything because that's not the thing that's changing. Here's an example:

Suppose thread 1 is calling this array-copying code, generating `Dest1` from `Source`. Suppose also that thread 2 already has `Dest2` generated by the same means. This means `Source[0]` and `Dest2[0]` both refer to the same single string. Now suppose thread 2 runs `Dest2[0] := ''` to clear the first element of its array. That's going to decrement the reference count of our string without any protection from thread 1's actions. If thread 1 uses non-interlocked operations to modify the reference count of that string at the same time thread 2 is modifying it, then you have a race condition. That thread 1 locked access to `Source` is irrelevant because thread 2 isn't acting on `Source`. It's only acting on a string that happens to be referenced by `Source`.